# How to edit /etc/fstab from a fedora live session?

Tags: filesystems, fedora, live, recovery

How do I get write access to a partition on my hard drive from a fedora live session?

I have done something wrong to my /etc/fstab in my main install and now it only boots into emergency mode. I can boot into a fedora live session from a usb drive but I can't work out how to edit the /etc/fstab file.

Fedora 34 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

noone answered this question,  so I reinstalled the system from the live usb system